# Different options for nodes for positive and negative bars in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I am having a problem with pgfplots when I want to change options for my nodes.

For example if I just want to increase the distance between the bars and the nodes I can use the `yshift` option and it works fine if I just have bars which go in one direction, but if I have bars which go in both directions (positive and negative) it obviously doesn't work if I just use `yshift=5pt`. Another example of the problem would be if I want to use different anchors for the nodes depending if the bars are positiv or negativ.

So I was wondering if there is a general way to change the behavior of the nodes depending on the kind of bars they belong to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{daten.dat}
X Y Y_error
0 -.3 .2
3 -.5 .3
6  .5 .1
8  1  .3
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{
every node near coord/.append style = {yshift=5pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    extra y ticks       = 0,
    extra y tick labels = ,
    extra y tick style  = {grid = major},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
   ybar,
   height=0.5\textwidth,
   width=0.5\textwidth,
   symbolic x coords={0,3,6,8},
   ymin=-1,
   ymax=3,
   xtick=data,                  
   ytick={-1, -0.5,...,2.5},
   ]
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error]{daten.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the use of the `axis` option `visualization depends on` the `yshift` of each node is calculated from the `Y` and `Y_error` columns of the data file as follow:

> sign(y) * y_error = abs(y)/y * y_error

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{daten.dat}
X Y Y_error
0 -.3 .2
3 -.5 .3
6  .5 .1
8  1  .3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    extra y ticks = 0,
    extra y tick labels = ,
    extra y tick style = {grid = major},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ybar,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    symbolic x coords={0,3,6,8},
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    ymin=-1.5,
    ymax=2,
    xtick={0,3,6,8},
    visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*\thisrow{Y_error} \as \myshift,
    every node near coord/.append style = {shift={(axis direction cs:0,\myshift)}}]
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error {daten.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. The only problem I have now, is that when I add more plots and I want to add a legend as well, it just takes the legendentries from one of the two axis and if there is one plot with just positive/negative values it ignores that plot for the legend. Do you have any suggestions for that problem?

Comment: @Gilean0709 I almost got a solution also for this :-)

Comment: @Gilean0709 maybe...

Comment: @Gilean0709 now it works much better, no more need of two `axis` environments.

Comment: Ah way nicer and cleaner!

Comment: @Red This is really great and helps a lot! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Red! This is a great answer, which I used for a similar plot. I [ran into a bit of trouble because mine used symbolic x coords](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200571/7329), though, but it turned out that [replacing `shift={(axis direction cs:0,\myshift)}` with `shift={(0,transformdirectiony(\myshift))}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200575/7329) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the alignment is only changing the anchor so to be able to get a sign-independent padding you can simply increase the height of the node. With a little more tweaks for giving some space for the nodes it should do the trick.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{daten.dat}
X Y Y_error
0 -.3 .2
3 -.5 .3
6  .5 .1
8  1  .3
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{
every node near coord/.style = {minimum height=1cm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    extra y ticks       = 0,
    extra y tick labels = ,
    extra y tick style  = {grid = major},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
   ybar,
   height=0.5\textwidth,
   width=0.5\textwidth,
   symbolic x coords={0,3,6,8},
   ymin=-1,
   ymax=3,
   xtick=data,                  
   ytick={-1, -0.5,...,2.5},
   ]
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error]{daten.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]