# Expressing a y-only shift with `axis direction cs` with symbolic x coords

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, coordinates

I have a vertical bar chart with error bars. I want to put a star just above or below the error bar where the results are significant.

I achieved this using the very neat trick provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130318/7329).

Here is a minimal example:

[image: vertical bar chart with error bars]

It works, but my problem is that, as opposed to what was the case in [the original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130313/7329), my x coordinates are symbolic. This results in error messages like this:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `0' has not been defined 
with 'symbolic x coords={α,β,γ,δ}... Maybe it has been misspelled?.
```

My real plots have a lot more stuff than that, but here is the code for producing the example above:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
    X Y Y_error Label
    α -0.06 0.33 \\
    β -0.51 0.19 $\star$
    γ -0.80 0.19 $\star$
    δ 0.54 0.27 \\
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
    X Y Y_error Label
    α -0.04 0.33 \\
    β -0.85 0.17 $\star$
    γ 0.89 0.15 $\star$
    δ 0.36 0.31 $\star$ \\
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[
        enlargelimits=0.15, 
        symbolic x coords={α,β,γ,δ},
        xtick=data,
        ybar,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.1+\thisrow{Y_error}) \as \myshift,
        every node near coord/.append style={
          anchor=center,shift={(axis direction cs:0,\myshift)},font={\bfseries},
        }]
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
          table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error, meta=Label] {data1.dat};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
          table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error, meta=Label] {data2.dat};
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The heart of the problem seems to be with `shift={(axis direction cs:0,\myshift)}`. Having `0` for the x component doesn't make sense for symbolic coords, but I haven't found a way to express a "stand alone y shift". Am I missing something obvious?

It's not a show stopper, but I get tons of error messages and it's preventing me from tikzexternalizing those plots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When only one component is required, the pgf math function `transformdirectiony()` should be used instead. So you can replace

```
shift={(axis direction cs:0,\myshift)}
```

with

```
shift={(0,transformdirectiony(\myshift))}
```

to apply a zero shift in the x-direction and the calculated shift in the y-direction. The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
    X Y Y_error Label
    α -0.06 0.33 \\
    β -0.51 0.19 $\star$
    γ -0.80 0.19 $\star$
    δ 0.54 0.27 \\
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
    X Y Y_error Label
    α -0.04 0.33 \\
    β -0.85 0.17 $\star$
    γ 0.89 0.15 $\star$
    δ 0.36 0.31 $\star$ \\
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[
        enlargelimits=0.15, 
        symbolic x coords={α,β,γ,δ},
        xtick=data,
        ybar,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.1+\thisrow{Y_error}) \as \myshift,
        every node near coord/.append style={
          anchor=center,shift={(0,transformdirectiony(\myshift))},font={\bfseries},
        }]
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
          table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error, meta=Label] {data1.dat};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
          table[x=X, y=Y, y error=Y_error, meta=Label] {data2.dat};
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the output (same as your original, but with no pesky errors `:-)`):

[image]