# Add error bars to scatter plot with labels and classes

Tags: tikz-pgf, error-bars

What I want to do is to add a vertical error bar (column ey in the table) on each point.
I tried to add:

```
%error bars/.cd,
%y dir=both,
%y explicit,
```

But it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[
    %axis x line=center,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=left,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel=Requirement (\#sentences),
    ylabel=mean F1,
    %axis y line=none,
    %hide y axis,
    xmin=-50,xmax=320,
    ymin=40, ymax=100,
    xtick={0, 100, 200, 300},
    xticklabels={0, 100, 100 + 100, highres},
    %xticklabel style={rotate=20},
    ]

    \addplot[
    scatter/classes={a={blue}, b={red}, c={green}, d={black}},
    scatter,
    only marks,%
    %error bars/.cd,
    %y dir=both,
    %y explicit,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords*={\Label},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label},
    ]%
    table[meta=class, x=x, y=y, y error=ey]{
        x   y   ey  class   label
        0   72  3   a   model1
        100 77  2   b   model2
        200 63  5   c   model3
        300 89  7   d   model4
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I added statement **plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]** and error bars are there but they're into the labels and I'll need to move the labels so that they're clear, any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[
    %axis x line=center,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=left,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel=Requirement (\#sentences),
    ylabel=mean F1,
    %axis y line=none,
    %hide y axis,
    xmin=-50,xmax=320,
    ymin=40, ymax=100,
    xtick={0, 100, 200, 300},
    xticklabels={0, 100, 100 + 100, highres},
    %xticklabel style={rotate=20},
    ]

    \addplot[
    scatter/classes={a={blue}, b={red}, c={green}, d={black}},
    scatter,
    only marks,%
    %error bars/.cd,
    %y dir=both,
    %y explicit,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords*={\Label},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label},
    ]%
    plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
    table[meta=class, x=x, y=y, y error=ey]{
        x   y   ey  class   label
        0   72  3   a   model1
        100 77  2   b   model2
        200 63  5   c   model3
        300 89  7   d   model4
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit] before the table statement but now the error bars are into the labels, so I'll need to move the labels a little big left, any idea what I'll need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I could more or less copy [the tricks of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130318/121799) and it seems to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{axis}[
    %axis x line=center,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=left,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel=Requirement (\#sentences),
    ylabel=mean F1,
    %axis y line=none,
    %hide y axis,
    xmin=-50,xmax=320,
    ymin=40, ymax=100,
    xtick={0, 100, 200, 300},
    xticklabels={0, 100, 100 + 100, highres},
    %xticklabel style={rotate=20},
    ]

    \addplot[
    scatter/classes={a={blue}, b={red}, c={green}, d={black}},
    scatter,
    only marks,%
    %error bars/.cd,
    %y dir=both,
    %y explicit,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{ey} \as \myshift,
    every node near coord/.append style = {shift={(axis direction
    cs:0,\myshift)}},
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords*={\Label},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label},
    ]%
    plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
    table[meta=class, x=x, y=y, y error=ey]{
        x   y   ey  class   label
        0   72  3   a   model1
        100 77  2   b   model2
        200 63  5   c   model3
        300 89  7   d   model4
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What might be more useful than the actual answer is how one can search and find such posts. All I did was a google picture search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com error bars nodes near coords` and clicked on promising pictures and tried to select one that appears reasonably elegant.

Comment: The search method site:tex.stackexchange.com query in Google image was amazing! Thanks a lot.